# How to create a IDENTITY primarykey column with Inheritance-per-class?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to inherit multiple `@Entity`s, and each one should increment the primary key by a database sequence, using:

`id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regclass)`

I therefore tried using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` as follows:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    //auto generates the id on database side
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {

}
```

Result:

`org.hibernate.MappingException: Cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> mapping for BaseEntity.class`

Why? And how can I use the id strategy with inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

Rather than use `@Inheritance`, you can use a `@MappedSuperclass` and I believe what you're trying to accomplish will work just fine.

If you need `@Inheritance`, you will need to resort to using `PROPERTY`-based annotations rather than `FIELD` and override the getter in each subclass as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Override
public Long getId() { ... }
```

Comment: Ok I see, `@MappedSuperclass` did it!